Вероятность выпадения при броске 4-х кубиков с 20-ю гранями
Помогите решить ряд задач:
Какова вероятность выпадения при броске 4-х кубиков хотя бы ОДНОЙ 20-ки на одном из 3-х кубиков:
1−((19÷20)×(19÷20)×(19÷20))+(19÷20)
Так?
Какова вероятность выпадения при броске 4-х кубиков хотя бы ДВУХ 20-ок на двух из 3-х кубиков:
(1÷20)×(1÷20)+(1÷20)+(1÷20)
Так?
Какова вероятность выпадения при броске 4-х кубиков ТРЁХ 20-ок на 3-х кубиках:
(1÷20)×(1÷20)×(1÷20)+(1÷20)
Так?
Pss
Во всех случаях бросается 4 кости с 20-ю гранями.
В первом варианте нужно получить одну 20-ку на одном из трёх кубиков, хотя бросали четыре куба.
Во втором варианте нужно получить две 20-ки на двух кубах из трёх. Хотя также бросали 4 куба.
А в третьем варианте нужно получить три 20-ки на трёх кубах, хотя также бросали 4 куба.
Psss
Три проверяемых куба можно определять самостоятельно
Pssss
Наверное я неверно поступаю, что всегда считаю 4-ый куб отдельно. Если мы кидаем 4 куба и сами выбираем какие из них проверять, то нет разницы сколько из 4-х кубов мы будем проверять. Так получается?
В таком случае нужно учитывать сразу 4 куба. Бросаем 4 куба. И какова вероятность, что выпадет одна 20-ка, две 20-ки, три 20-ки…

Такой кубик называют икосаэдром :) Лично мне непонятен вопрос. Что означает уточнение "хотя бы на одном из трех кубиков", "на двух из трех кубиков" — это при броске четырех? Что имеется в виду? В первой части — что в любой тройке из этих четырех всегда будет хотя бы одна 20? Т.е. что должно выпасть две двадцатки? Или в чем смысл "на одном из трех"? Только третий вопрос звучит приемлемо, хотя и тавтологично: понятно, что три двадцатки выпадают на трех кубиках. Неясно только, ровно три надо, или хотя бы три?

Во всех случаях бросается 4 кости с 20-ю гранями.
В первом варианте нужно получить одну 20-ку на одном из трёх кубиков. Во втором варианте две 20-ки на двух кубах из трёх. А в третьем три 20-ки на трёх кубах. При том мы всегда бросаем 4 куба

То есть учитываем результат только на трёх любых костях, а бросаем четыре

Какова вероятность выпадения при броске 4-х кубиков хотя бы ОДНОЙ 20-ки на одном из 3-х кубиков Варианты интерпретации. 1) После броска можно выбрать хотя бы одну тройку кубиков такую, что в ней есть хотя бы одна 20; 2) После броска в любой тройке кубиков есть хотя бы одна 20. Это разные задачи, и условие не позволяет определить, какой вариант следует рассматривать.

Опять 25... "на трёх любых костях" — как минимум две трактовки: кости выбирает бросивший; на любых 3 костях, случайным образом выбранных... Знаете что, дайте условие дословно, как его получили вы, а не как вы его пересказываете...

Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что автор ну никак не хочет точно и однозначно определить условия задач...

на одном из трёх кубиков - на каких трёх из четырёх? Ясности пока не прибавилось. Исходное условие вас просили привести - где оно?

Наверное я неверно поступаю, что всегда считаю 4-ый куб отдельно.
Если мы кидаем 4 куба и сами выбираем какие из них проверять, то нет разницы сколько из 4-х кубов мы будем проверять. Так получается?


Бросаем 4 куба. И какова вероятность, что выпадет одна 20-ка, две 20-ки, три 20-ки…

Ну, с этим уже можно работать :)
Итак, есть N костей с вероятностью выпадения нужного нам значения p. Задача — найти вероятность выпадения ровно m нужных значений из N.
Все очень просто (так и подмывает сказать "тоже мне, бином Ньютона!" :) ). Вероятность, что m костей дадут нужное значение, а остальные N-m — ненужное, равна pm*(1-p)N-m, причем вариантов выбора этих m костей — СNm, т.е. P(N,m,p) =  СNm*pm*(1-p)N-m.
Значит, вероятность получить ровно одну 20-ку из броска четырех костей:
P(4,1,1/20) = 4!/(3!*1!) * (1/20)^1 * (19/20)^3

Вероятность получить ровно две 20-ки из броска четырех костей:
P(4,2,1/20) = 4!/(2!*2!) * (1/20)^2 * (19/20)^2

Вероятность получить ровно три 20-ки из броска четырех костей:
P(4,3,1/20) = 4!/(3!*1!) * (1/20)^3 * (19/20)^1

Но как только вопрос ставится "хотя бы", надо учитывать, что "хотя бы одна", например — это 1, 2, 3 или 4. И суммировать соответствующие вероятности (но проще вычесть из 1 вероятность "ни одной" — P(4,0,1/20)). Хотя бы две — это сумма "две, или три, или четыре". Или 1 минус сумма "ни одной или одна".
Собственно, всё...
Что именно вам требуется считать — смотрите сами...
P.S. Что сумма P(N,m,p) по m от 0 до N равна 1, сомнений не вызывает? :)
Ведь это таки и есть бином Ньютона: (p+(1-p))N
P.P.S. Давайте посмотрим детальнее, раз непонятно...
У нас есть N... ну, скажем, фонариков, которые могут светиться (*), или быть выключены (_). Вероятность одного фонарика светиться - p, быть выключенным — 1-p=q. Нам надо выяснить вероятность, что светятся ровно m фонариков. Начнем с того, что выясним вероятность того, что светятся первые m фонариков в цепочке:
***...***____...____
\__ m __/\__ N-m __/

Вот вероятности:
ppp...pppqqqq...qqqq

Их надо перемножить, так как это одно событие — вероятность, что И первый, И второй и так далее фонарики в требуемом состоянии. Имеем
pmqN-m.
Но сколько всего может быть таких цепочек с m звездочками? Нам надо выбрать m мест из общего числа N для того, чтоб их поместить, в остальные поместим выключенные фонарики. Способов их выбрать — число сочетаний m элементов из N, СNm.
Все цепочки независимы, так что вероятности для каждой цепочки просто складываются с остальными, а так как они равны, то вероятность для одной цепочки надо умножить на это число сочетаний. Получается  СNmpmqN-m.
Так понятнее?

Прошу прощения за свои малые познания. Я мало что понял из написанного, но у меня теперь хотя бы есть формулы. Буду вникать. Воспользуюсь екселем для наглядности. Спасибо Вам за терпение и ответ. Доброго Вам дня и здоровья :)

См. P.P.S. в ответе.

Мне страшно неудобно перед Вами. Но боюсь это всё равно слишком сложно для меня.
Если Вас не затруднит, подскажите, пожалуйста, если бы мы бросили 4 кости с 20-ю гранями, но искали бы уже 19 и 20 скажем, то верно ли я изменил пример? 4!/(3!*1!) * (2/20)^1 * (18/20)^3

Да, вероятность p при этом становится 2/20.

Отвечая на вопрос “Какова вероятность выпадения при броске 4-х кубиков ТРЁХ 20-ок на 3-х кубиках:”, немного запутанно написано, но если я правильно понимаю, то, нужно получить 60 очков исключительно двадцатками.
Думаю надо действовать так:

Найдем общее число исходов броска.
Исходы можно представлять в виде (x,y,z,q), где x - сколько очков выпало на первой кости (от 1 до 20), y - сколько очков выпало на второй кости (от 1 до 20), z - сколько очков выпало на третьей кости (от 1 до 20) и т.д.
Т.е. 20х20х20х20=160 000.
Найдем общее число подходящих вариантов.
Т.е. подбираем такие исходы, которые дают в сумме 60 на трех кубиках, а на четвертом, что угодно, но не 20.
(20, 20, 20, 1), (20,20,1,20), (20,1,20,20) ,(1, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 2), (20,20,2,20), (20,2,20,20) ,(2, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 3), (20,20,3,20), (20,3,20,20) ,(3, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 4), (20,20,4,20), (20,4,20,20) ,(4, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 5), (20,20,5,20), (20,5,20,20) ,(5, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 6), (20,20,6,20), (20,6,20,20) ,(6, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 7),(20,20,7,20), (20,7,20,20) ,(7, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 8),(20,20,8,20), (20,8,20,20) ,(8, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 9),(20,20,9,20), (20,9,20,20) ,(9, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 10),(20,20,10,20), (20,10,20,20) ,(10, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 11),(20,20,11,20), (20,11,20,20) ,(11, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 12),(20,20,12,20), (20,12,20,20) ,(12, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 13),(20,20,13,20), (20,13,20,20) ,(13, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 14),(20,20,14,20), (20,14,20,20) ,(14, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 15),(20,20,15,20), (20,15,20,20) ,(15, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 16),(20,20,16,20), (20,160,20,20) ,(16, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 17),(20,20,17,20), (20,17,20,20) ,(17, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 18),(20,20,18,20), (20,18,20,20) ,(18, 20,20,20)
(20, 20, 20, 19),(20,20,19,20), (20,19,20,20) ,(19, 20,20,20)

Получили 76 подходящих исходов.

Искомая вероятность P=76/160 000=0.000475

Предполагаю ,что так

Да, но проще просто написать (19/20)(1/20)³С³₄, не выписывать же для каждой задачи в общем случае все возможные варианты? :)

То есть такой метод применим ко всем трём задачам?

Прошу прощения, если неясно расписал. Да Вы всё правильно поняли. Во всех случаях бросается 4 кости с 20-ю гранями. В первом варианте задачи нужно получить одну 20-ку на одном из трёх кубиков. Во втором варианте две 20-ки на двух кубах из трёх. А в третьем три 20-ки на трёх кубах. При том мы всегда бросаем 4 куба

"То есть такой метод применим ко всем трём задачам?" Расписывания всех вариантов? Да сколько угодно :) Если бы еще понимать условия этих задач...

"не выписывать же для каждой задачи в общем случае все возможные варианты? :)" – ну конечно же можно не выписывать, никто Вас не осудит за это. При этом с точки зрения наглядности и обучения, думаю это хорошо для задающего вопрос. Хотя могу ошибаться

"То есть такой метод применим ко всем трём задачам?"- Логика в том, чтобы посчитать все допустимые варианты, все ВОЗМОЖНЫЕ варианты и разделить одно на другое. Единственное, для меня не очевидны условия других задач (бросают 4 кубика, нужно две 20-и на 3х из них), просто не могу до конца их осмыслить, поэтому и решение по ним не до конца понятно
